# VBA - Scraping data from 100 plus identical sheets with variable number of rows into single consolidated sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very much a self taught user of vba but have always been able to cobble together what I need from questions on this site or similar but this one has me stumped so any help greatly received.

I've written some VBA to scrape data from 100 odd excel files with an identical source sheet (stored in several different folders) into a single consolidated sheet in a separate workbook. The number of columns is constant (84) but the row count in source sheets is variable (also contains formulas so has to not count rows containing formula returning "") and I want the consolidated sheet to have all records from each file without gaps.

I've written something that works but is horrendously slow and I feel the issue is I'm basically defining each cell to scrape which is a lot of records when what I want to identify the range with variables (start row (always 5) to Last Row (variable) and take in one go and scrape to the consol sheet, with the destination's only variable being the next available row, before moving to the next file but my attempts to adapt code to do that get throwing errors.

```
Sub Test_Macro()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFole, queue As Collection
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set queue = New Collection
    queue.Add fso.GetFolder("D:\Example\Example")
    '^^^ UPDATE THIS FILE PATH TO FOLDER WHERE THE RETURNED SCORECARDS ARE STORED. IF FOLDERS STORED IN MULTIPLE FOLDERS THIS SHOULD BE THE FOLDER CONTAINING SUBFOLDERS ^^^

    Do While queue.Count > 0
        Set oFolder = queue(1)
        queue.Remove 1 'dequeue
        For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
            queue.Add oSubfolder
        Next oSubfolder
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files

            y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consol").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 '<<< Finds next available row after a value in consol sheet

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(oFile.path) '<<< Sets variable to the open performance scorecard
            Set ws = wb.Sheets("Detailed Summary") '<<< Defines sheet in the open scorecard to scrape from

            wb.Unprotect "Password"
            ws.Unprotect "Password"

            wsLR = ws.Columns("B").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues).Row '<<< Defines the range containing data in the open scorecard

            For x = 5 To wsLR 
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consol").Cells(y, 1) = ws.Cells(x, 2)
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consol").Cells(y, 2) = ws.Cells(x, 3)
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consol").Cells(y, 3) = ws.Cells(x, 4) 'etc. imagine going on to...
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consol").Cells(y, 84) = ws.Cells(x, 85)

                y = y + 1
            Next x

            wb.Close (Saved = False)
        Next oFile
    Loop

End Sub
```

Any help doing the same thing but quicker would be amazing! Thanks

Comment: 1. You really need to work on your variable names.  
2. Get & Transform (on the Data tab) can be extremely efficient for cases like these. You can read all files from a folder and transform them in a lot of different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments which may help speeding up, assuming the slow-down is in the sheet accessing:

Note that NONE of the below has been debugged, and I have assumed that your code as written works, but just slowly.

*Use the `after` keyword for robustness*

```
wsLR = ws.Columns("B").Find("*", after:=ws.cells(1,2), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues).Row '<<< Defines the range containing data in the open scorecard
```

Read the range into a VBA array, and then write to the "Consol" worksheet.
Something like:

```
Dim scraped As Variant
With ws
    scraped = .Range(.Cells(5, 2), .Cells(wsLR, 85))
End With

Dim consolRng As Range
Set consolRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consol").Cells(y, 1)

Set consolRng = consolRng.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(scraped, 1), columnsize:=UBound(scraped, 2))
consolRng = scraped
```

You might be able to speed things up even more by consolidating all of the workbooks into a single VBA array, and then writing the entire thing out as one operation, instead of the multiple writes (one per workbook) implied by the code above, but that might be more complex and more prone to memory issues, depending on the size of the data.

Another potential slowdown is in using the FileSystemObject to collect the names of the desired files.  That can be made faster by shelling to the command prompt and using the DIR command.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. This is easily 1/100th of the run time with identical functionality. I'd experimented with ranges but always got errors but I see how 'scraped' is a Variant which I think is where my experiments went wrong.

Comment: @JamesWilliams Yes, reading/writing to/from a worksheet is a very expensive operation in terms of time spent.  Using the VBA array to process the data is usually at least an order of magnitude faster; in your case, even more.  Another option that is sometimes useful is to copy/paste the entire range in one step, especially if you have to copy formulas.